# Question about proof on inequalities

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

I have four equations:

1. $n\geq 5k+2$
2. $n_1\geq 5k_1+1$
3. $n_2\geq 5k_2 +1$
4. $n=n_1+n_2$

What I want to get eventually is $k_1+k_2=k$, but it seems like I cannot say that as I get
$n\geq 5(k_1+k_2)+2$ and $n\geq 5k+2$, which does not necessarily mean $k_1+k_2=k$.

Is there another way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: @Student I disagree with your last statement. For example, $ n = 7 \geq 5 \times 0 + 2$, $n_1  = 6 \geq 5 \times 1 + 1, n_2 = 1 \geq 5 \times 0 + 1$ and $ k \not \geq k_1 + k_2$.

Comment: I don't think you can conclude anything.  If we set $n, k, n_2, n_1$ we can set $k_1, k_2$ to anything small as we like.  ($n=2,n_1=1, n_2=1, k=0; k_1 = -739857489375349$, and $k_2 =-\pi$ for example).  Or if we set $k_1,k_2$ we can have $k$ be as small as we like. $n=2, n_1=n_2 = 1, k_1=-7, k_2=-35$ and $k =-57489672976345$ for example.

Comment: Basically if $n, n_1,n_2$ are known we know that $k$ a and $k_1+k_2$ are both bound above of $\frac {n-2}5$ but nothing more.  $k$ can be anything less and $k_1 + k_2$ can be anything less.

Comment: @CalvinLin I agree, I'll delete this comment, didn't think it through.